# Lightweight, flat batteries

Tags: batteries

I want to design a multifunction device that has a laser pointer as one of its attributes.  The laser pointer module I'm considering uses two AA batteries but these batteries are too big/heavy for the device.  Are there any flat baterries I can use instead?  My device needs approx 3-5mW output.

I don't know the diff btw volts, amps or watts; but I'm starting to learn.  Please point me to any good educational resources.

Comment: I edited your question to conform more to our standards on Stackexchange --- our questions and answers are meant to be useful for future readers so we don't embellish them with greetings and signatures. I also changed your title to reflect what you are asking about to help future readers find this question if they have a similar problem. That said, if you disagree with my edits, please feel free to revert or re-edit it yourself.

Comment: YOu need a spec for battery life and if rechargeable is an option, and most important weight, size specs for your app.'s power source.

Answer (score 4):

Cell phone batteries are nice and flat (0.230 inches vs. 0.560 inches for AA in my phone) and have similar voltage of 3.7 volts. Mine is a bit wide though (1.440 inches). Two AA would be about 3.3 to 3.4 volts when new, so depending on the specifics the cell battery **may** be directly useable. They are generally Lithium Ion if not Lithium Polymer, both are as light as you may possibly find. There are general battery chargers that could work with them as well (I found one at Radio Shack, cheap on sale, $25-$30 generally as I recall.)

You could also check with a hobby store if you have one nearby, they have many types of batteries for small RC cars that may be to your liking.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what kind of battery life you want, you may be able to use a [Button Cell/Coin Cell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Button_cell).

These type of batteries are typically used in low-power compact devices like watches, hearing aids, small laser pointers, etc.